# Is Hask even a category?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask:

> Consider:
>
> ```
> undef1 = undefined :: a -> b
> undef2 = \_ -> undefined
> ```
>
> Note that these are not the same value:
>
> ```
> seq undef1 () = undefined
> seq undef2 () = ()
> ```
>
> This might be a problem, because `undef1 . id = undef2`. In order to make **Hask** a category, we define two functions `f` and `g` as the same morphism if `f x = g x` for all `x`. Thus `undef1` and `undef2` are different *values*, but the same *morphism* in **Hask**.

What does it mean or how can I check, that:
`undef1` and `undef2` are different values, but the same morphism?

Comment: The "different values" bit can be witnessed, as above, by any experiment that distinguishes output (or the lack of it). The "same morphism" idea is an attempt to ride roughshod over the disagreement in observable behaviour by saying which observations (just applications, not seqs) matter. But be suspicious: they do not say what x ranges over (values? or for higher-order functions, morphisms?) or in what sense the outputs should be equal.

Comment: [Nope](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/comment-page-1/).

Comment: Jokes aside, mechanically checking that two functions `f` and `g` are the same morphism (let's pretend the word means something in this context) is equivalent to deciding the halting problem. So no, you cannot in general check it. In each individual case you may (or may not) be able to prove it.

Comment: @n.m. mechanically proving that two functions of arbitrary type are the same morphism is impossible, but for many particular types (including highly polymorphic types, that are actually quite small thanks to parametricity) it can be done using [universe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe.html). And even where that isn't applicable, practically speaking it's often quite easy to find out that two functions are nonequal, using something like QuickCheck.

Comment: Mechanical checkability is irrelevant. A definition of the criteria that must be proven would be progress.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand it..

Comment: even why can't we have: `undefined . id = undefined` ?

Comment: @garychaudhry we could easily have that, it would just require the `.` operator to be defined a bit differently, like† ``f . g = f `seq` g `seq` \x->f(g x)``. Just, there would be no real use to this, because in practice, the only use of a function is to actually evaluate it. (†Actually, the compiler seems to optimise the above `seq`s away for that reason; the `undefined` only triggers an error when you use [`pseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:pseq) instead which is never optimised out.)

Comment: `undefined` breaks all kinds of stuff. Is `()` an initial object? Is `(,)` a product? Is `Either` a coproduct? Not if `undefined` is around. Etc etc

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter..

Comment: @n.m. `()` is terminal and `(,)` is a product in lazy PCF with bottoms, with respect to observational equality. As Andrej Bauer noted in the link, the main issue, rather than bottoms, is not having a notion of equality and semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell, we have this idea that every expression can be evaluated to a particular "value", and we might be interested in determining if two expressions have the "same" value.

Informally, we know that some values (e.g., value `2` and `3` of type `Integer`) can be compared directly.  Other values, like `sqrt` and `id` of type `Double -> Double` can be compared, as @pigworker notes, by constructing an expression that "witnesses" a difference in directly comparable values:

```
sqrt 4 = 2
id 4 = 4
```

Here, we can conclude that `sqrt` and `id` are different values.  If there is no such witness, then the values are the same.

If we look at the monomorphic specializations of `undef1` and `undef2` to the type `() -> ()` given by:

```
undef1, undef2 :: () -> ()
undef1 = undefined
undef2 = \_ -> undefined
```

how can we tell if these are different values?

Well, we need to find an expression that witnesses a difference, and one is given above.  The two expressions:

```
> seq undef1 ()
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
> seq undef2 ()
()
>
```

have different values, according to GHCi.  We could also show this directly, using our understanding of Haskell semantics:

```
seq undef1 ()
-- use defn of undef1
= seq undefined ()
-- seq semantics:  WHNF of undefined is _|_, so value is _|_
= _|_

seq undef2 ()
-- use defn of undef2
= seq (\_ -> undefined) ()
-- seq semantics: (\_ -> undefined) is already in WHNF and is not _|_,
--   so value is second arg ()
= ()
```

So, what's the problem?  Well, when considering **Hask** as a *category* where the objects are types and the morphisms are (monomorphic) functions, we implicitly need a concept of identity/equality for objects and morphisms.

Object identity/equality is easy:  two objects (monomorphic Haskell types) are equal if and only if they are the same type.  Morphism identity/equality is harder.  Because morphisms in **Hask** are Haskell values (of monomorphic function types), it would be tempting to define equality of morphisms to be the same as equality of values, as above.

**If we used this definition**, then `undef1` and `undef2` would be different morphisms, because we have proved they are different Haskell values above.

However, if we compared `undef1 . id` and `undef2`, we would discover that they have the *same* value.  That is, there is no expression that witnesses a difference between them.  Proving this is a little tough, but see below.

Anyway, we now have a contradiction in our **Hask** category theory.  Because `id` is the (polymorphic family of) identity morphisms in **Hask**, we must have:

```
undef1 
= undef1 . id                            -- because `id` is identity
= undef2                                 -- same value
```

so we simultaneously have `undef1 /= undef2` because of the witness above, but `undef1 = undef2` by the previous argument.

The only way to avoid this contradiction is to give up the idea of defining equality of morphisms in **Hask** as equality of the underlying Haskell values.

One alternative definition of equality of morphisms in **Hask** that has been offered is the weaker definition that two morphisms `f` and `g` are equal if and only if they satisfy `f x = g x` for all values `x` (including `_|_`).  Note that there's still an ambiguity here.  If `f x` and `g x` are *themselves* Haskell functions and so morphisms, does `f x = g x` mean equality of the *morphisms* `f x` and `g x` or equality of the Haskell *values* `f x` and `g x`?  Let's ignore this problem for now.

Under this alternative definition, `undef1` and `undef2` **are** equal as morphisms, because we can show `undef1 x = undef2 x` for all possible values `x` of type `()` (namely `()` and `_|_`).  That is, applied to `()`, they give:

```
undef1 ()
-- defn of undef1
= undefined ()
-- application of an undefined function
= _|_

undef2 ()
-- defn of undef2
= (\_ -> undefined) ()
-- application of a lambda
= undefined
-- semantics of undefined
= _|_
```

and applied to `_|_` they give:

```
undef1 _|_
-- defn of undef1
= undefined _|_
-- application of an undefined function
= _|_

undef2 _|_
-- defn of undef2
= (\_ -> undefined) _|_
-- application of a lambda
= undefined
-- semantics of undefined
= _|_
```

Similarly, `undef1 . id` and `undef2` can be shown to be equal as morphisms in **Hask** by this definition (in fact, they were equal as Haskell values which implies they're equal according to the weaker definition of equality of **Hask** morphisms), so there's no contradiction.

However, if you follow the link provided by @n.m., you can see that there's more work to do in terms of formalizing the meaning of equality of Haskell values and precisely giving an appropriate definition of equality of **Hask** morphisms before we'd really feel comfortable believing that there *is* a contradiction-free **Hask** category.

#### Proof that `undef1 . id = undef2` as Haskell Values

For the reasons above, this proof is necessarily a little informal, but here's the idea.

If we are trying to witness a difference between functions `f` and `g`, the only way a witnessing expression can *use* these values is by applying them to a value `x` or by evaluating them to WHNF using `seq`.  If `f` and `g` are known to be equal as **Hask** morphisms, then we already have `f x = g x` for all `x`, so no expression can witness a difference based on application.  The only remaining thing to check is that when they are evaluated to WHNF they are either both defined (in which case, by the previous assumption, they will yield the same values when applied) or they are both undefined.

So, for `undef1 . id` and `undef2`, we just need to ensure that they are either both defined or both undefined when evaluated to WHNF.  It's easy to see that they both, in fact, have defined WHNFs:

```
undef1 . id 
-- defn of composition
= \x -> undef1 (id x)
-- this is a lambda, so it is in WHNF and is defined

undef2
-- defn of undef2
= \_ -> undefined
-- this is a lambda, so it is in WHNF and is defined
```

We already established above that `undef1 x = undef2 x` for all `x`.  Technically, we ought to show that:

```
(undef1 . id) x
-- defn of composition
= (\x -> undef1 (id x)) x
-- lambda application
= undef1 (id x)
-- defn of id
= undef1 x
```

with equality as Haskell values for all `x`, which establishes that `(undef1 . id) x = undef2 x` for all `x`.  Together with the fact that both have defined WHNFs above, this is enough to show that `undef1 . id = undef2` with equality as Haskell values.