# Does Hask form a theoretically valid category? Or it just pretends to be one?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

**Hask** looks like a subcategory of the **SET** - category of all sets and single-argument functions between them. However, seems like it fails to preserve `id` when it comes down to the `undefined`: `seq undefined ()` fails with exception as it suppose to, however `seq (undefined . id) () = seq (id . undefined) () = ()`. Obviously, `id` acts wrongly.

Is there a way to (theoretically at least) resolve this issue and make **Hask** a category indeed? Except throwing `undefined` away?

Comment: This is very nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485660/is-hask-even-a-category.  In short, **Hask** can't be a category if you use a concept of equality of morphisms (i.e., Haskell values of monomorphic function types) where `seq x () = _|_` and `seq y () = ()` implies that `x` and `y` aren't equal, thanks to exactly the contradiction you point out.  Under a weaker definition of equality that allows `x` and `y` to be equal morphisms *despite* this difference in behavior, **Hask** *might* be a category, but it's still an open question.

Comment: At least, I *think* it's still an open question...

Comment: @K.A.Buhr, thanks for answer(s), both are great. However, considering two morphisms "the same" while they act differently seems to go well with category theory: it simply does not care that much about undergoing meaning/representation of morphism. Unless you take it down to some concrete category like SET is; then one can not ignore what stands behind them. Obviously, mathematical functions, especially viewed as subsets of a Cartesian product, are equal in one and only one case: when the same input produces the same output. And yet I personally regret that Haskell fails to delive abs. purity.

Comment: There is another potential resolution (besides equating non-co-terminating things): choose a different composition operation than `(.)`. (One needs to be a bit careful anyway: `(.)` is an *arrow* of **Hask**, not an operation on arrows of **Hask**, and there is an implicit reification, often omitted, needed to convert from the in-language construct to the out-of-language operation on arrows.)

Comment: @DanielWagner, well, when it comes down to the SET, composition is always part of it? Am I wrong? It always acts on the set and thus belongs to it. However you point is definitely smart, thanks. Unfortunately, it gonna look really ugly if one solves theoretical issue in such a fashion. Damn reality!

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov When you ask "composition is always part of it", what is "it"? Certainly the next sentence (paraphrased) "X always acts on set Y, therefore X belongs to Y" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: For a concrete proposal for an alternative composition operation, consider (the reification of) `f ... g = seq f (seq g (\x -> f (g x)))`. This does at least have the property that `undefined ... id = id ... undefined = undefined`... [or does it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51332928/791604)

Comment: [Loose and Fast reasoning is morally correct](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html)