# Why does this function seem to hide its embedded exception?

Tags: haskell, exception

While commenting on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51331179/791604), I discovered an apparent break in referential transparency. In ghci:

```
> f g h = g `seq` h `seq` \x -> g (h x)
> seq (f undefined id) ()
()
> seq (undefined `seq` id `seq` \x -> undefined (id x)) ()
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:3:14 in interactive:Ghci9
```

Why isn't the first one bottom? (GHC 8.2.2 in case it matters -- I don't have any other versions installed on this machine at the moment.)

Comment: GHC 8.2.1 produces the same behavior

Comment: It looks to me like the lambda in `f` is getting floated. Weird, but maybe somehow valid. Or maybe `seq` isn't respected when floating lambdas in some versions of ghc.

Comment: I could reproduce this surprising behavior on 8.0 and 8.4. It certainly looks wrong. A compiled program throws the exception.

Comment: This doesn't appear to happen in a compiled program, only in ghci.

Comment: 8.4.2 also has the same behavior. This looks very wrong.

Comment: Simplified case: ``f g = g `seq` \x -> x``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this is [Trac #14002](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14002).  If you do a:

```
> :set -fpedantic-bottoms
```

or define `f` in a file and load it into GHCi, then both expressions cause an exception.

The bug report claims it's difficult to fix without incurring a performance penalty.

Comment: Amazing, the bug even uses the same function as my example. =D